# How to extract a private key from .PFX file to .PEM file using AES-GCM as a password-based encryption?

Tags: encryption, openssl, password-based-encryption, pkcs8

I'm trying to extract a private key from a **.PFX** file to a **.PEM** file format. I was able to do it using  `Aes128Cbc` in either .NET or OpenSSL:

**.NET:**

```
PbeParameters pbeParams = new PbeParameters(PbeEncryptionAlgorithm.Aes128Cbc, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, 1);
byte[] privateKey = rsaPrivateKey.ExportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey("pass123", pbeParams);

Console.WriteLine("Generating PEM file...\n");
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY", privateKey);
Pem.PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(pemObject);
```

**OpenSSL:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path/to/pfx -nocerts -out path/to/output
```

For both output options, I could check the key by using:

```
openssl rsa -check -noout -in private-key.pem
```

Now, I'm trying to change the Password-Based Encryption algorithm to use AES-GCM but I don't know how to do it or even if it is possible. I've tried to use `AesGcm` on .NET and also searched into the options of `openssl pkcs12` command but I couldn't find a way to do it:

```
byte[] privateKeyBytes = rsaPrivateKey.ExportPkcs8PrivateKey();

byte[] salt = GenerateRandomBytes(16);
byte[] iv = GenerateRandomBytes(12);
int iterations = 100_000;
int keySize = 256;
int tagSize = 128 / 8;

byte[] key = DeriveKey("pass123", salt, iterations, keySize);

byte[] encryptedData, tag;
using (AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(key))
{
    encryptedData = new byte[privateKeyBytes.Length];
    tag = new byte[tagSize];
    aesGcm.Encrypt(iv, privateKeyBytes, encryptedData, tag);
}

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY", encryptedData);
PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter);
pemWriter.WriteObject(pemObject);

// ...

public static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int length)
{
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
    using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
    }
    return randomBytes;
}

public static byte[] DeriveKey(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int keySize)
{
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations))
    {
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
    }
}
```

I had also tried to concatenate all info into the PEM file:

```
Array.Copy(pemData, salt, 16);
Array.Copy(pemData, 16, iv, 0, 12);
Array.Copy(pemData, 28, encryptedData, 0, privateKeyBytes.Length);
Array.Copy(pemData, 28 + privateKeyBytes.Length, tag, 0, tagSize);
```

I don't much understand about all PKCS standards but after reading about PKCS #12 and after looking for some answers among the internet I'm wondering if it's possible to do it or if there is some kind of impossibility that I couldn't see yet.

Comment: You don't say which PEM format you want of the many that exist, but your first code sample suggests you want the one in [rfc7468 section 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-11). Note this is not just "any kind of encryption of PKCS8 that I invented", it is a specific format defined in rfc5208 and rfc5958 and neither your second or third samples are anything like it. I'm not aware of any AES-GCM scheme defined for or compatible with PKCS8 encryption; do you have a reference for what you want? (OpenSSL definitely won't do anything other than CBC.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 , you're right,  I'm trying to generate a PEM file of an Encrypted Private Key Info. It was a request from the security team to replace Aes128Cbc claiming that CBC is a vulnerable cipher that doesn't provide integrity. I read the RFCs and had the same conclusion of you that AES-GCM scheme is not defined for PKCS8, but I'm wondering, is that safe to use Aes128Cbc for PBE? Shouldn't we need integrity to keep a file with a private key info?

Comment: I keep going on RFCs, but I'm a little confused on which RFC should I use. The rfc5208 uses pkcs5 for password based encryption which I believe doesn't specifies AEAS-GCM. The rfc5958 that obsoletes rfc5208 says that: "Changed imports from PKCS #5 to [RFC5912] and [RFC5911]", but I still couldn't find a list of algorithms that is recommended to use. Also, I'm not sure if the rfc5912 and rfc5911 are available at OpenSSL or .NET. I mean, is these rfcs a standard?

Comment: A privatekey in PKCS8 format (which is what is encrypted in EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo) is a combination of effectively-random and strictly-structured that is hard to effectively tamper, so CBC is _probably_ safe, and certainly is _very_ widely used without any reported problem or attack. However if you want (real, cryptographic) integrity -- and I wouldn't disagree with that goal -- a widely supported way is to put it in PKCS12 (aka PFX) which uses the common PKCS8 encryption (CBC) for the keybag, but also has a password-based MAC on the file. ...

Comment: ... PKCS12/PFX is _usually_ used for key PLUS cert or cert-chain; the standard allows key-only and e.g. OpenSSL can do that, but some software might not in which case the convention is to provide a dummy self-signed cert which is ignored when the key is used; yes this isn't elegant but it works. There is no registry or comprehensive list of algorithms for PKCS5 -- which is extensible by design -- but I've never seen anything besides PBES2 from 2898/8018 or the schemes in PKCS12/7292 appendix B-C (and to hone my earlier comment, I've never seen an AEAD scheme that fits into PBES2).

Comment: ... (added) but PKCS12/PFX is almost always handled in binary, not PEM, if that is important. There is no technical reason it _can't_ be PEMized, people just haven't chosen to.